# Java JNI call FindClass fails from a C++ program

Tags: java, environment-variables, c++

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/993067/Calling-Java-from-Cplusplus-with-JNI) tutorial which calls a Java class from a C++ program. A Java virtual machine is instantiated but the call to FindClass fails. The code sample is directly from the tutorial:

MyTest.java

```
public class MyTest {
    private static int magic_counter=777;

    public static void mymain() { 
       System.out.println("Hello, World in java from mymain");
       System.out.println(magic_counter);
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
int main()
{
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
   JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
   options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=./";
   vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
   vm_args.nOptions = 1;
   vm_args.options
   = options;
   vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

   jint rc = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
   delete options;   
   if (rc != JNI_OK) {
         std::cin.get();
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   cout << "JVM load succeeded: Version ";
   jint ver = env->GetVersion();
   cout << ((ver>>16)&0x0f) << "."<<(ver&0x0f) << endl;

   jclass cls2 = env->FindClass("MyTest");  
   if(cls2 == nullptr) {
       cerr << "ERROR: class not found !";
   }
   else {
       cout << "Class MyTest found" << endl;
       jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls2, "mymain", "()V");  
       if(mid == nullptr)
           cerr << "ERROR: method void mymain() not found !" << endl;
       else {
           env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls2, mid);                      
           cout << endl;
       }
   }

   jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
   cin.get();
}
```

g++ command:

```
g++ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server  main.cpp -o SearchEngineCpp -ljvm
```

I run `javac SearchEngine.java` to create the class file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you run `javac SearchEngine.java` to generate `SearchEngine.class` as mentioned in the tutorial (*"We compile this code from the command line: `javac MyTest.java`"*)

Comment: Yes I did. I will update my question.

Comment: Please also include the exact command with which you executed the compiled binary, and the complete error message

Comment: I call the executable from the command line with ./SearchEngineCpp. The program exits because FindClass returns NULL; there is no other error. When I try the run the program from Eclipse CDT, the JVM fails to instantiate and the program fails sooner.

Comment: You may have more than one version of JDK on your system - make sure that your class was compiled with the same version of java (`javac -version`) that you are linking the executable to

Comment: Yes you are right. Javac was from JDK 11 and I was using JDK 8.

Comment: OK so you can either call the JDK 8 version explicitly (`/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac`) or if you want a system-wide solution, use `update-alternatives` to configure java/javac/javap to use the openjdk-8 versions

Comment: Please post it as an answer and I will mark the question as closed

Comment: I have added a revised answer below - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can occur if you have multiple versions of the JDK on your system, and the default Java version for the `javac` class compiler is different from the `libjvm.so` with which you are linking your executable.

For example, on my 18.04 system:

```
$ update-alternatives --list javac
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
```

and

```
$ javac -version
javac 11.0.6
```

then

```
$ javac MyTest.java
$
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server ./SearchEngineCpp 
JVM load succeeded: Version 1.8
ERROR: class not found !
```

You can work around this by calling the appropriate java compiler explicitly ex.

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac MyTest.java
$
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server ./SearchEngineCpp 
JVM load succeeded: Version 1.8
Class MyTest found
Hello, World in java from mymain
777
```

For a persistent system-wide solution, use the `update-alternatives` mechanism to choose the appropriate Java version:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
sudo update-alternatives --config javap
```

Comment: Thank for spotting that problem, but the program fails before that.  FindClass() returns NULL. I never get to use GetStaticMethodID().

Comment: @rur2641 Sorry, in that case I'm out of ideas. BTW that's why I asked you to include the complete error message in your question. I assume the `SearchEngine.class` is in the directory from which you are executing the command?

Comment: Yes, all the files are in the same folder. I also updated the question to be exactly like the sample ode.